# Asp.Net files appears as code rather than serving web pages

Tags: web-hosting, asp.net

I have created my website in ASP.Net and I have uploaded my site through FileZilla FTP server Software. But when i use My domain name in browser, it just displays Code instead of Design view.

I'm new to this

I don't know the exact error so please guide me.

**P.S**

- Vb.net is the code behind file
- `.aspx.vb` is the file extension of code behind file and
- for design page `.aspx` is the file extension

Comment: I may help someone to answer your question if you tell us what language you are using and the file extension of your code files.

Comment: Vb.net is the code behind file .aspx.vb is the file extension of code behind file and for design page .aspx is the file extension

Comment: Okay. Sounds like normal stuff. It has been too long since I worked with IIS to really answer your question. But I think there is enough here that someone should be able to help.

Comment: Can you confirm that your server is on windows, and also that your server is setup correctly to parse the aspx code?

Comment: What is your domain name, or can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Maybe your domain doesn't support asp.net websites. You might want to confirm this.

Comment: Okay...lets simplify this. Please tell me the URL that you are browsing to where you are experiencing this behavior? Based on my experience, I'd assume that you've chosen the wrong hosting package. I'll take a look at the URL and will let you know for certain.

Comment: This is impossible to diagnose without actually looking at your url.  Likely issue is that you are not on an IIS or Mono server which can serve ASP.net pages.  If you are on IIS, then somewhere in the IIS pipeline ASP.net pages are either not installed or handler mappings for asp.net extension are not pointing properly to allow for the pages to run.   Also another issue might be that your pages actually do not have an aspx extension and might have somthing like page.aspx.html but you have your system setup to hide file extensions.  Give us the URL and we can help you further.